# Asp.net membership provider determination

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider

When studying ASP.net membership provider I faced with such a question and could not find an answer.

It is clear that We have Database, where provider stores information like name/pwd etc. , but how does it find the right key for the current user? Is it transfered via HTTP headers and saved in users' cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the [forms authentication ticket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) is contained inside a cookie. The cookie is stored at clients side, and sent back to server with the page request for authentication .

If you use [ASP.NET Universal Providers' Membership](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx), I would like to suggest to use ASP.Net Login control; it works right out of the box with Membership provider without writing any code.